# Bootstrap .well - changing color with react props

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm using bootstrap & reactjs.
I have .well-component on my page. User should be able to change its color. Color stores in {this.props.color}.
I'm trying to change it like this:

```js
 <div className="well lead" style={{backgroundColor:'{this.props.color}'}} style={{marginTop:'20px'}} >
```

But it doesn't work & I don't have any ideas, why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you used `'this.props.color'` which is a plain string.
Should be instead:

```
style={{backgroundColor: this.props.color}}
```

And by the way, you better put all style properties within the same object:

```
 <div className="well lead" style={{backgroundColor: this.props.color, marginTop:'20px'}} >
```

Comment: thank you! Your second notice is very important. I tried to remove '{ }' before, but it works only if put style properties within one object